# react-native-paper DataTable styles

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am using react-native-paper DataTable to layout my screen. So far, everything is going ok, but I have not been able to delete the line that separates the rows in the table (DataTable.Row). Do you know how to do it?  You can refer to the documentation [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [DataTable.Row](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table-row.html) documentation shows it has a `style` prop, you can use that to set the bottom border width to `0`

```
    <DataTable.Row style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
       ...
    </DataTable.Row>
```